# Port 8089 is blocked

Tags: cisco, router, port, port-forwarding

I am trying to Port Forward 8089 and I am having quite a bit of trouble doing so! Looking for a possible hint at what I am doing incorrectly... I myself tried setting this up a number of times then a 3rd Party Network Guru also took a look at this and saw nothing wrong with it. I am the (Self Taught) Network Admin and to my knowledge I cannot see anything wrong. I did not originally setup this network so my assumption is that there is some option that I am glossing over that was turned on/off by the previous "Admin"

This is not ran through a Domain server and just going through the router itself to port forward

The router I am using is **"RV082  10/100 8-Port VPN Router"**
I am using the normal routine (With this router) to portforward

[image: Picture of port Forward Setup]

Firewall settings picture allowing port 8089 through

[image: The Image]

When I test it on https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/   It says that is closed on my external IP (Port 8089)

The IP I am port forwarding with is correct(Triple Checked)

I have done a full reset of the network and applied all above settings

The service I am trying to connect to is a phone system called "Grandstream" or "UCM6202"... Now I can navigate to UCM6202 and can login INTERNALLY but when I try to access it externally I am being blocked by port 8089.

Strange thing being is that on the day of installation this port was "Open"

Comment: Highly recommend setting your destination IP, so that all traffic through that port goes only to your service.

Answer (score 0):

Well nothing was wrong on my side... The "UCM6202" was configured incorrectly and I have gotten in contact with the individuals who set the "UCM6202" up!

Thank you very much!